# How do you use arrays with RazorEngine?

Tags: c#, arrays, razorengine

```
string templ = @"@Model.Name[0] @Model.Name[1]";
string result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(templ, new { Name = "Hello" });

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This is my output

```
H e
```

I am trying to figure how I can fit an array in there, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
new { Name[0] = "Hello", Name[1] = "World"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the Razor engine. Your template string is fine, and the Razor engine is evaluating it exactly as you would expect, given that the value you provided for `Name` was a `string` and not an array.

You just have to initialize the array correctly. Try this:

```
string result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(
    templ,
    new { 
        Name = new[] { "Hello", "World" } 
    });
```

**Further Reading**

- [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)
- [Implicitly Typed Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)
- [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)